# Graph query language GO FROM: How to start from the last returned property?

Tags: nebula-graph, graph-query

Is there any way to implement GO FROM from the property returned by the previous query, specifically:

```
GO FROM "XXX" over web yield properties(edge).dst_url_vid as dst_url_vid
| GO FROM $-.dst_url_vid over sec_to_sens_type yield dst(edge)
```

The above statement is to start from a specific node, then get a `property` on the edge, and this is `vid` in the graph. The next step is to start from this `vid` and continue the query later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
GO FROM ‘xxx’ over web yield web._dst AS id | go from $-.id over
```

Though this is from the destination of the web edge, since `go` statements do not support starting from a node's property, even if the property value is the same as the vid.